# Client Machine Unique ID

Tags: javascript, jsp, web-applications, servlets

Is there any scripting method to generate a fixed unique ID of client machine?
My situation is:

When the browser request the video from web server, I need to store a unique ID when to identify the client. Using Unique ID such as UUID won't work as when the client open a new tab and watch the same video, it will generate another ID but the reality is it is the same client.

It must be generic that it will be compatible with most OS. Using WMI can grab the client MAC address but it only works on Windows platform. As we know javascript and Server Side scripting like JSP (which i'm using now) could not get most of OS level information such as MAC address and Internal IP address.

I also trying to avoid from using Java Applet and another external program which I can grab client's internal IP address as it won't work if JRE is disabled.

I prefer using javascripts,JSP or Servlet. However any other idea will also be appreciated ^^

Any Idea guys?

Thanks^^

Comment: What exactly do you need this ID for? The normal practice to uniquely identify clients is to introduce a registration/login form. OpenID (like here on SO!) can make things much easier for the client.

Comment: Actually there is a server with database that act as a network monitor (it called mediator). The information of the client that access the content server will be sent to this mediator and stored in its database. Those information will be analysed then. The number of client accessing the content is one of the parameter to be analysed. So I need to unique thing from the client to differentiate amongs them. Generating unique ID using javascript won't work as it will generate new ID if the client requesting the content on another tab. So the number of clients will be incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

How about generating an `UUID` and storing it as a cookie ?  This way you can uniquely identify a machine on revisits until the user clears his cache or browses incognito

Comment: Thanks parapura! Looks like using cookies is the only way. I'll give it a try =D

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want to create and store session data. I would take a deeper look into setting/getting cookie data, and see if you cannot set a cookie to solve this issue.

If this is to secure/prevent users from watching two videos, I would be careful implementing a client-side solution.

You may also be able to take other things into consideration, including user-agent, IP address, cookies, etc.

Comment: looks like using cookies is the only way. I'll give it a try then. What i'm trying to do is not preventing the user from watching two videos but identifies that it is the same client even he/she is watching two videos. Generate UID won't work, as it generates new ID if the client open another tab and request the same page.